# Need help changing side bar code due to static Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I used a tutorial online to create a slide out side bar (similar to the facebook app).

It's based on using a table view as the side bar.

I cannot change the size (row height) of an individual cell as the table is set to dynamic (as specified by the tutorial. I change the row height in the IB and it makes no difference when running. It turns out I need a static table to use this.

When I change the table to static, it breaks my app with the following code causing the problem. I know a dynamic table is when you want to reuse cells and therefore dequeueReusableCell will cause a problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}
```

I don't have much experience with TableViews past this specific tutorial so just need a little bit of help amending the code so I can use a static table.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried tableView.rowHeight = 100.0; ?

Comment: It's just one cell I want to change the height of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table view isn't static, don't make it static to handle the row height. Instead, implement the table view delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return the appropriate height for each row.

Setting the height in the XIB / storyboard can have an effect but it depends on the overall configuration as to exactly what (if anything) it will do.